# What did the PIE prefix *kom- signify in

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european

[cumber | Origin and meaning of cumber by Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cumber)

> c. 1300, *cumbren, combren*, "to overthrow, destroy, probably a shortening of  *acombren* "obstructing progress,"
>   from Old French *encombrer*, from *combre* "obstruction, barrier,"
>   from Vulgar Latin **comboros* "that which is carried together," which is perhaps from a Gaulish word.
>
> The likely roots are PIE **kom* (see [com-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/com-?ref=etymonline_crossreference)) and [*bher-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*bher-?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_52553) (1) "to carry," also "to bear children."

Etymonline failed to explain the meaning of the prefix *** *kom***. The definitions below don't apply, because they contradict the meaning of *comboros. *comboros doesn't mean bearing 'beside, near, by, with' something.

> [kom](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/indoeurop.html#IR123200)    `Beside, near, by, with`.

Comment: Where it says "see *com*" -- see that. If you're not happy with the proposed etymology, you can either propose an alternative, or toss it on the "unknown" pile.

Comment: I dunno; _com_ means 'with', so 'bear with' or 'bear together' and 'encumbrance' are in the same ball park. Certainly in the same one as Latin _impediment_, which meant 'luggage'; i.e, something to trip over.

Comment: @jlawler Thanks. Latin *impediment* `meant 'luggage'` ? I thought that it concerned shackles on the feet, from the PIE root *ped- (see http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=impediment&allowed_in_frame=0)?

Comment: Ever travelled a long distance on foot carrying a heavy box? You put it down whenever you can, you swear at it a lot, and you trip over it unless you're very careful. Feet are multi-purpose organs.

Comment: Look at its cognates:  Germanic *ge*, Slavic *къ*.  Both Italo-Celtic *com* and Germanic *ge* often convey a connotation of *com*-pletion.  Many other prefixes also get used as “perfectivizers”.